# Merge macro tables in SAS

Tags: merge, macros, sas

I'm a beginner in SAS so I am unfamiliar with syntax. I have two datasets that were created using macros. 
(macro: https://gist.github.com/statgeek/2f27939fd72d1dd7d8c8669cd39d7e67)

```
DATA test1; 
     set sashelp.class;
     if prxmatch('m/M/oi', sex);
     female=ifn( sex='F',1,0);
RUN; 

%table_char(test1, height weight age, sex, female, test1_table_char); 

DATA test2; 
     set sashelp.class;
     if prxmatch('m/F/oi', sex);
     female=ifn( sex='F',1,0);
RUN; 

%table_char(test2, height weight age, sex, female, test2_table_char);
```

Desired Output:

```
               Male       Female 
Height 
  Count 
  Mean
  Median
   .
   .
Weight
Count 
  Mean
  Median
   .
   .
Sex
  M
  F
Etc
```

I wwould like to merge the two macro tables together created with %table_char by Name. How should I call th two tables so I can merge?

```
DATA final_merge; 
     merge test1_table_char   test2_table_char;
     by NAME;
RUN;
```

Comment: what is your final goal.  there seems no need of macro in the scenario here

Comment: I want to merge the tables created for test1 and test2 by NAME. I don't need a macro to merge, but I don't know how to merge the tables.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that can show expected output?

Comment: Did you create the macro you are calling?  Do you know how the datasets it generates are formatted?  You need to know that before you can know how to put two of them together.

Comment: I did not create the macro that is in the link. I know that the dataset it generates is formatted in a single columned demographic table. Since I am a beginner, I don't realy know how to edit the macro to include multiple groups. Instead I am just creating multiple of the same table and merging them together to get what I need (posted above).

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to do is append the datasets.

```
 data final;
   set test1 test2;
 run;
```

You need not split and merge datasets, you can simply do.

```
  DATA final; 
 set sashelp.class;
 female=ifn( sex='F',1,0);
RUN;
```

if you want to merge sort the datasets and then merge datasets

```
 proc sort data =test1;
 by your_variable;
  run;

 proc sort data =test2;
 by your_variable;
  run;

  data final;
  merge test1 test2
   by your_variable;
  run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Above is an example of what I want to get done so I would still like to use the split and merge method since there is additional details I'd like to keep: https://gist.github.com/statgeek/2f27939fd72d1dd7d8c8669cd39d7e67

Comment: which means you need to append the data not merge

Comment: So if I want test1_table_char and test2_table_char merged, will that be sufficient?

Comment: When you say merge, do you mean you want the two data sets aligned side-by-side, or do you want them stacked together?

Comment: Side by side. The github link should give the macro I used and the sashelp.class should give the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Combine or merge test1 and test2 by NAME:

```
proc sort data=work.test1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   by name;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
run;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

proc sort data=work.test2;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   by name;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
run;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

data work.test;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   merge work.test1 work.test2;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   by name;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
run;
```

Producing this result:

```
Name       Sex    Age    Height    Weight    female

Alfred      M      14     69.0      112.5       0
Alice       F      13     56.5       84.0       1
Barbara     F      13     65.3       98.0       1
Carol       F      14     62.8      102.5       1
Henry       M      14     63.5      102.5       0
James       M      12     57.3       83.0       0
Jane        F      12     59.8       84.5       1
Janet       F      15     62.5      112.5       1
Jeffrey     M      13     62.5       84.0       0
John        M      12     59.0       99.5       0
Joyce       F      11     51.3       50.5       1
Judy        F      14     64.3       90.0       1
Louise      F      12     56.3       77.0       1
Mary        F      15     66.5      112.0       1
Philip      M      16     72.0      150.0       0
Robert      M      12     64.8      128.0       0
Ronald      M      15     67.0      133.0       0
Thomas      M      11     57.5       85.0       0
William     M      15     66.5      112.0       0
```

Run macro with the merged output:

```
%table_char(test, height weight age, sex, female, test_table_char);
```

Produces the following result:

```
categorical        value

Sex
F                      9(47.4%)
M                     10(52.6%)
Height
Count(Missing)     19(0)
Mean (SD)           62.3(5.1)
Median (IQR)        62.8(57.5 - 66.5
Range               51.3 - 72.0
90th Percentile     69.0
Weight
Count(Missing)     19(0)
Mean (SD)          100.0(22.8)
Median (IQR)        99.5(84.0 - 112.
Range               50.5 - 150.0
90th Percentile    133.0
Age
Count(Missing)     19(0)
Mean (SD)           13.3(1.5)
Median (IQR)        13.0(12.0 - 15.0
Range               11.0 - 16.0
90th Percentile     15.0
Female                 9(47.4%)
```

Comment: I am trying to get two value columns side by side with separate statistics for males and females